# How does one uses html validation for a form when javascript is off on the client side

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

How does one validate via HTML when javascript is turned off? Via onclick my button will called a form validation from a javascript. However, if a user turn off javascript, my HTML validation should be the one validating, as a failsafe if javascript is turn off, but whenever I click on my button, nothing happened. Why ?

```html
<form class="reservationForm">
  <h1>RESERVATION FORM</h1>
  <section class="form-group">
    <label>First Name:*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name" id="fname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{99}" title="Please input a name" required>

    <label>Last Name:*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last name" id="lname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{99}" title="Please input a name" required>

    <label>Email address:*</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" id="resemail" pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$" title="Please input a valid email" required>

    <label>Contact Number:*</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter contact number" id="cnumber" pattern="[\d]{8}" maxlength="8" title="please input a valid number" required>

    <label>Date:*</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="resdate" required>

    <p>
      <label>Time:*</label> <br>
      <select name="time">
        <option>5:00 PM</option>
        <option>6:00 PM</option>
        <option>7:00 PM</option>
        <option>8:00 PM</option>
        <option>9:00 PM</option>
        <option>10:00 PM</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <label>Number of people:*</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter pax" id="pax" pattern="[\d]{3}" maxlength="3" title="Please input a vaid number" required>

    <label>Request:</label><br>
    <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Request"></textarea>
  </section>

  <button type="button" class="btnform" onclick="return validateReservationForm() ">Submit Reservation</button>

</form>
```

Comment: You validate on the server. You ***!!!ALWAYS!!!*** validate on the server. The client-side validation is mostly for user convenience, it's not supposed to be the single point of filtering input.

Comment: [Should you validate server side if you're validating client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942498/should-you-validate-server-side-if-youre-validating-client-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button must have `type="submit"` in order to submit your form.